# Removing conditional "new" keyword dependency from a method

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm currently in the middle of learning DI & IoC principles. So, I stumbled upon such scenario where I have a method with a dependency that can not be injected via constructor. Also, I can not pass it as a method parameter because creation of that instance is conditional + it can only be instanciated with parameters of its own. Here is a super-simplified version of my Employee and WorkYear classes:

```
public abstract class Employee
{
    private List<WorkYear> _workYears;
    // other private fields....

    protected Employee(IDependency1 dep, etc...)
    {
         WorkYears = new List<WorkYear>();

         // other components initialization....
    }

    public IEnumerable<WorkYear> WorkYears
    {
        get => _workYears.AsReadOnly();
        private set => _workYears = value.ToList();
    }

    public void StartWorking(DateTime joinedCompany)
    {
        List<PayPeriod> periods = // Calculating periods...
        WorkYear year = WorkYears.FirstOrDefault(y => y.CurrentYear == joinedCompany.Year);

        if (year == null)
        {
            // Here is the problem:
            year = new WorkYear(joinedCompany.Year, this, periods);

            AddYear(year);
        }
        else
        {
            // Logic when year not null
        }

        year.RecalculateAllTime();
    }

    public void AddYear(WorkYear workYear) => _workYears.Add(workYear);

    // More code...
}


public class WorkYear  
{ 
    public WorkYear(int currentYear, Employee employee, List<PayPeriod> periods)
    {
        Employee = employee;
        EmployeeId = employee.Id;
        CurrentYear = currentYear;
        PayPeriods = periods ?? new List<PayPeriod>();

        foreach (PayPeriod period in PayPeriods)
        {
            period.WorkYear = this;
            period.WorkYearId = Id;
        }
    }

     // More code...
}
```

As you can see I only need a new instance of a WorkYear if Employee doesn't already have it. I found a thread that suggested to use simple factory class to solve similar issue. Such solution could work, but how do I handle parameters without which the WorkYear can not be instantiated?

Would be great to see an example of how to approach this problem.

Comment: Maybe I missed something, but what is the dependency you're trying to remove?

Comment: new WorkYear(joinedCompany.Year, this, periods);

Comment: @НикитаУрюпин That's no dependency, IMO it's fine as-is.

Comment: Why can't you pass it in through the constructor? Your derived classes will just need to declare the dependancy too, e.g. `Manager(IWorkYearFactory factory)`

Comment: @JSteward is it okay then if my factory method would take in all the parameters that WorkYear constructor must consume? Like this: `var workYear = workYearFactory.Create(typeof(WorkYear), joinedCompany.Year, this, periods);`

Comment: There are several things off with your code. Your `StartWorking` method appears to be in charge of handling work years, yet your `WorkYears` is a publicly accessible list. What's to stop me from directly adding to this list or even replacing it entirely? If anything, it should be an `IEnumerable<WorkYear>` and `WorkYear`'s constructor should be internal. There are no dependencies here, unless you want to introduce one to manage the logic of adding new work years.

Comment: You have a dependency on `WorkYear` already in `WorkYears` property

Comment: @JuanR as I mentioned, this code is simplified version, real workYear list look like this `public IEnumerable<WorkYear> WorkYears
        {
            get => _workYears.AsReadOnly();
            private set => _workYears = value.ToList();
        }` but the question is that how do I remove "new" keyword dependency from my code.

Comment: It's OK to simplify code, but whatever you post must still represent a minimal, complete and verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @JuanR Sorry, I will edit it to make it more clear. However, are you trying to say that having `new WorkYear(joinedCompany.Year, this, periods);` is not a dependency?

Comment: Yes, that is not a dependency. Your class is currently managing work years. Then again, it depends on what you understand as a dependency.

Comment: Dependencies are more about logic than the data. Business rules change more so than data changes. You abstract out the logic that deals with the business rules so that you can more easily change those rules (in code) in the future. Think about it like this:  Today you're using PDFSharp to generate PDFs. That is a dependency. Tomorrow, PDFSharp changes its licensing model that is prohibitive for you to use it. Now you want to use iTextSharp. How do you easily swap out those bits of logic if you scattered PDFSharp references all througout your code?

Comment: I think I may understand what you are trying to accomplish. I'll post an answer in a moment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an alternate approach using interfaces to hide the real objects.

Create an interface to represent your work years:

```
public interface IWorkYear
{
    int CurrentYear { get; }

    void RecalculateAllTime();
}
```

Have your `WorkYear` class implement it:

```
public class WorkYear : IWorkYear
{
    //Implementation code here
}
```

Create an interface to represent a provider:

```
public interface IWorkYearProvider
{        
    IWorkYear CreateNewWorkYear(int year, Employee employee, List<PayPeriod> periods);
}
```

Have your `Employee` class use the `IWorkYear` interface instead of the actual object:

```
public abstract class Employee
{
    private List<IWorkYear> _workYears;

    //Notice the dependency injection here
    public Employee(IWorkYearProvider workYearProvider)
    {
        WorkYearProvider = workYearProvider;
    }

    //Reference to the dependency
    public IWorkYearProvider WorkYearProvider { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<IWorkYear> WorkYears { get => _workYears.AsReadOnly(); private set => _workYears = value.ToList(); }
    public object Id { get; internal set; }

    public void StartWorking(DateTime joinedCompany)
    {
        List<PayPeriod> periods = null; // Calculating periods...
        IWorkYear year = WorkYears.FirstOrDefault(y => y.CurrentYear == joinedCompany.Year);

        if (year == null)
        {
            // Use the dependency to create the object
            year = WorkYearProvider.CreateNewWorkYear(joinedCompany.Year, this, periods);
            _workYears.Add(year);
        }
        else
        {
            // Logic when year not null
        }

        year.RecalculateAllTime();
    }

    // More code...
}
```

A couple of test classes I created to illustrate:

```
public class SampleEmployee : Employee
{
    public SampleEmployee(IWorkYearProvider provider) : base(provider) { }
}

public class SampleWorkYearProvider : IWorkYearProvider
{
    public IWorkYear CreateNewWorkYear(int year, Employee employee, List<PayPeriod> periods)
    {
        IWorkYear workYear = null;
        workYear = new WorkYear(year, employee, periods);
        return workYear;
    }        
}
```

Sample usage:

```
//Create your provider
IWorkYearProvider provider = new SampleWorkYearProvider();

//Inject it as a dependency
var employee = new SampleEmployee(provider);

//Call the method
employee.StartWorking(DateTime.Today);
```

The creation is now abstracted out.

I would much rather recommend you rethink your design. It would probably make more sense to abstract away the entire logic within `StartWorking`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I probably would rethink StartWorking as well. Not sure what class should be responsible for that though... Thank you for the response!

Comment: My pleasure. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, or why `newing up a work year needs to get abstracted. You'll see we can't really get too far. But let's take a look:

We can define a generic interface:

```
public interface IFactory<T, TData>
{
    T Create(TData data);
}
```

Then describe our data and implement:

```
public class WorkYearData
{
    WorkYearData(int currentYear, Employee employee, List<PayPeriod> periods)
    {
        CurrentYear = currentYear;
        Employee = employee;
        Periods = periods;
    }

    public int CurrentYear { get; }

    public Employee Employee { get; }

    public List<PayPeriod> Periods { get; }
}

public class WorkYearFactory : IFactory<WorkYear, WorkYearData>
{
    public WorkYear Create(WorkYearData data) 
        => new WorkYear(data.CurrentYear, data.Employee, data.Periods);
}
```

And finally update Employee

```
//Then
year = new WorkYear(joinedCompany.Year, this, periods);
//Now
year = _factory.Create(new WorkYearData(joinedCompany.Year, this, periods));
```

**As you can see we really haven't abstracted much, rather, just added indirection.**

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted to acomplish. However, insted of having `year = _factory.Create(new WorkYearData(joinedCompany.Year, this, periods));` do something like this: `year = _yearFactory.Create(joinedCompany.Year, this, periods);` that way you don't have to new up anything. Then when I would be unit testing StartWorking method, I can now provide a WorkYear mock object with predifined behavior so tests can be trully isolated.

Comment: You can definitely get rid of the `WorkYearData` class and do `_yearFactory.Create(joinedCompany.Year, this, periods);` that class was just so I could make the interface generic.

Comment: But now I'm quite confused about why newing up instance of class A inside of a method in class B is not a dependency. It is most definate that class B will depend on class A implementation.

Comment: Somewhere there's going to be a `new`, but we're dealing with nouns here, i.e. Employee, WorkYear. Abstracting their construction is just moving the new. Now the logic inside those objects is what really needs to be abstracted. For instance the `StartWorking` method could be hiding behind an interface and you could more easily change it's implementation. There's really no need to hide a DTO's creation but abstract your logic.

Answer (score 0):

First, injecting your code with an instance of `WorkYear` will not make your code independent of `WorkYear` as `Employee` still knows about this class (as in the list  `List<WorkYear> WorkYears` for example), therefore if you need DI you should talk with an interface that represents this class like `IWorkYear` (and here the list will be `List<IWorkYear> WorkYears` instead ).

Now for injecting and instantiating:

Make a factory class like:

```
public static class MyFactory
{
    public static object Create(Type classType, object[] data = null)
    {
        // create the class by reflection
    }
}
```

(To create a class by reflection check this: [Activator.CreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx))

Then change the signature of the method `StartWorking` so the type is injected into the method:

```
public void StartWorking(Type workYearType, DateTime joinedCompany)
```

and the line:

```
year = new WorkYear(joinedCompany.Year, this, periods);
```

will be :

```
year = MyFactory.Create(classType, new object[]{ joinedCompany.Year, this, periods});
```

Comment: I feel like this aproach is an overkill, but that's deffinetly woth considering. Thank you for your response.